# Android reviews not visible?

Tags: android, google-play

I got 2 reviews and only can see them in the developer console. The corresponding ratings are visible in Google Play but the reviews not. I went through all the languages offered in the dropdown at the bottom of the webpage and couldn't find them. Why is this?